# How to prove that $x=y=1$ or $x=y=−1$ if $xy=1$?

Tags: number-theory, integers

I'm struggling with my current home assignment. If $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $xy=1$ how to prove that $x=y=1$ or $x=y=-1$? To achieve this, **only** the following properties can be used.

$\forall x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z}:$

1. $(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$;
2. $x+y=y+x$;
3. $x+0=x$;
4. $x+(-x)=0$;
5. $(xy)z=x(yz)$;
6. $xy=yx$;
7. $x\cdot 1=x$;
8. $x(y+z)=xy+xz$;
9. $xy=0 \implies x=0 \lor y=0$;
10. $x<y \veebar x=y \veebar x>y$;
11. $x<y \land y<z \implies x<z$;
12. $x<y \implies  x+z<y+z$;
13. $x<y \land z>0 \implies xz<yz$;
14. $0 \neq 1$;
15. $x+z=y+z \implies x=y$;
16. $-(-x)=x$;
17. $-(x+y)=(-x)+(-y)$;
18. $x\cdot 0=0$;
19. $z\neq 0 \land xz=yz \implies x=y$;
20. $(-x)y=-xy=x(-y)$.

A hint would be greatly appreciated.

As far as I understand, this is an exercise from this book: [The Real Numbers and Real Analysis, Bloch, Ethan D.](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387721767)

Comment: What is the purpose of the variable $z$?

Comment: The given properties often involve three variables, for instance, $(xy)z=x(yz)$

Comment: Welcome to math.se. Please show us what you've tried or where precisely you think you are having trouble. Raw questions posted like this are not well received on this site, especially homework problems. This question has also been asked and answered many times on the internet.

Comment: @Vaidville The given properties are missing all quantifiers anyway. For your particular question, $z$ is not needed

Comment: This is a Theorem that can be found exactly like that on [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Invertible_Integers_under_Multiplication)

Comment: The listed properties are all true for the rational numbers and for the real numbers, but your theorem is not true if we replace $\mathbb Z$ with the set of rationals or the set of reals. I think you need something more than that list. For example, the ProofWiki proof relies on another proof that relies on the fact that if $x\in\mathbb N$ and $x > 0$ then $x \geq 1.$

Answer (score 1):

If $xy = 1$ with elements in a commutative ring, then $x,y$ are invertible in $R$.

In the ring of integers, the invertible elements are $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $x, y$ must be non-zero, and have the same sign.

Then note that if $x, y$ is a solution, so is $-x, -y$, as $x y = (-x) \cdot (-y)$. Thus we may assume $x, y > 0$.

Now note that if $x > 1$, then $1 = x y > y > 0$, but there are no integers between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this: Let's prove it first, for $x>0,y>0$, later we'll prove the general case. Fix $x>1,x\in\mathbb{N}$ then we'll prove by induction $\nexists y\in\mathbb{N}, xy=1$, that is consider $A=\{y\in\mathbb{N}:xy>1 \}$

1)$1\in A$ Clearly, $x1=x>1$

2) Suppose $n\in A$, then $(n+1)x=nx+1>1+1>1$

Therefore, by the principle of induction $A=\mathbb{N}$

You have to prove now that if $x=1$ then the only solution is $y=1$, I believe the reasoning is very similar as above.

Now, clearly $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, otherwise if $x>0,y<0$ by the rules you said we can use $xy=yx<0<1$. So if $x<0\implies y<0$, choose $z=-x,z'=-y$ and you are in the above proved case.

Hopefully I made myself clear, otherwise feel free to ask and edit whatever you want. Have a nice day! :)